# Retrieve NHibernate.Collections.Generic.PersistentGenericBag as IList<T> using Reflection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection

I'm attempting to compare a transient object graph to an NHibernate-persisted object graph. Unfortunately my code breaks where properties of type `IList<T>` are concerned. The code below works fine with instances of `List<T>`, because `List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` AND `IList`. Unfortunately, NHibernate's PersistentGenericBag only implements `IList<T>`.

```
IList list1 = (IList)prop1.GetValue(object1, null);
IList list2 = (IList)prop2.GetValue(object2, null);
```

If either object1 or object2 is a PersistentGenericBag, I get an error such as:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown
by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[MyNamespace.MyClass]'
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.MyClass]'.
```

Is there a reliable way to retrieve the PersistentGenericBag instance as an IList<T> using reflection?

I had hoped the popular [Compare .NET Objects](http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/) class would help, but it fails with the exact same error.

**Edit:** All the answers below are on the right track. The problem was that the getter on the problematic `IList<T>` property was attempting a cast to `List<T>`, which obviously can't be done to a PersistentGenericBag. So, my fault for the misguided question.

Comment: The probable problem with the compare project is that it does not drill down into an object until it finds an IList implementation.

Comment: the error says you're trying to cast to List<T> (concrete), *not* IList<T> (interface)

Comment: PersistentGenericBag<T> *does* implement both IList and IList<T>, see http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/T_NHibernate_Collection_Generic_PersistentGenericBag_1.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: never mind. commenter is right, you CAN go straight to IList. I was focusing one the question as stated a little too hard to see the obvious even as I was coding the answer. doh!

Ok, you just need to dig a little bit deeper.

The base class of PersistentGenericBag is PersistentBag, which **does** implement IList.

```
var prop1 = typeof (Customer).GetProperty("Invoice");

// if you need it for something...
var listElementType = prop1.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

IList list1;


object obj = prop1.GetValue(object1, null);

if(obj is PersistentBag)
{
    list1 = (PersistentBag)obj;
}
else 
{
    list1 = (IList)obj;
}

foreach (object item in list1)
{
    // do whatever you wanted.
}
```

Tested and works for bags. Take it to the logical conclusion for other list/set/collection types that you might encounter.

So, the short answer is; If you KNOW it is a bag, you can just cast the object first to PersistentBag and then to IList...

```
IList list = (PersistentBag)obj;
```

If you DONT KNOW then use some conditional logic as shown.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `IList` to compare two collections.

Cast to `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: For whatever reason, "(IEnumerable)prop1.GetValue(object1, null);" yields the exact same error.

Comment: Are you sure prop1 and object1 are the property and object you are looking for? Did you look at them (and the invocation result) in the debugger?